# Selecting distinct data from two columns in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select, multiple-columns

I have a table with a list of messages between users. The table structure:

```
Receiver | Sender | Subject   | Message

Daniel   | Admin  | Title 1   | Message 1
Admin    | Daniel | Title 2   | Message 2
Daniel   | Admin  | Title 3   | Message 3
Daniel   | John   | Title 4   | Message 4
```

Assume I am logged in as Daniel. I want to show a list of people with whom I am communicating (irrespective of whether I am the sender or receiver), as well as the latest subject/message. Something like:

```
Admin | Title 3 | Message 3
John  | Title 4 | Message 4
```

I've tried a million ways to do this but I just can't put my finger on it!

It would also be helpful if somebody could help me differentiate between latest messages in which I'm the sender and those in which I am the receiver (e.g., some kind of if statement). However, I haven't attemped this myself yet so it's not a pressing issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: My english is very bad,please forgive!   How i compare which is lastest message? primary id? communicate time?

Comment: The primary id (highest number). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Receiver, Subject, Message FROM m WHERE Sender='<your_name>'
UNION ALL
SELECT Sender, Subject, Message FROM m WHERE Receiver='<your_name>'
```

This will simply return the list of names that had contact with given name. You can manipulate this code to also return whether it was a sender or receiver

***Edit*** *(after exchanging comments)*

This will show you last message from each conversation, whether a person you're looking for was a sender or receiver. The code is based on my temporary table, you have to tweak it a little bit to suit your needs.

```
SELECT MAX(id), conv, message FROM (
  SELECT id , CONCAT(sender,'-',receiver) AS 'conversation', message FROM t
  WHERE
    sender = '<person>'
  GROUP BY rec
  UNION
  SELECT id , CONCAT(rec,'-',sender) AS 'conversation', message FROM t
  WHERE
    rec = '<person>'
  GROUP BY sender
) as t
GROUP BY convsersation, message
```

### **Explanation**

1. In first subquery I am getting latest message for each conversation where person you are looking for was a sender.
2. Second subquery gives us the result of latest message for conversations where that person was a receiver.
3. CONCAT is used so we can merge conversations together
4. We wrap it in the main query that will output only MAX(id) which is the latest message.
5. If you need to know whether person in question was receiver or sender, you can add another column in the subqueries:

   SELECT MAX(id), conversation, message, type FROM (
     SELECT id , CONCAT(sender,'-',receiver) AS 'conversation', message, 'sender' AS 'type' FROM t
     WHERE
       sender = ''
     GROUP BY rec
     UNION
     SELECT id , CONCAT(rec,'-',sender) AS 'conversation', message, 'receiver' AS 'type' FROM t
     WHERE
       rec = ''
     GROUP BY sender
   ) as t
   GROUP BY convsersation

(for some reason I can't make a code block on this second query, could someone edit it please)

Comment: If I am correct this will output all of the messages, not just the latest message.

Comment: All of the messages, yes. If you'd like to list messages in chronological order you would need a date table or at least id(unique, auto_increment)

Comment: I would like only the latest message from each person with which I am communicating. Not all the messages in chronological order. Thanks!

Comment: Based on what you have replied to symcbean - you do not want Admin->Daniel to show up if Daniel->Admin showed up already right?

Answer (score 0):

To get the output you specify....

```
SELECT i.correspondent, m.subject, i.msg
FROM (
SELECT sender AS correspondent, MAX(message) msg
FROM mesages
WHERE receiver='Daniel'
GROUP BY sender
UNION
SELECT receiver AS correspondent, MAX(message)
FROM mesages
WHERE sender='Daniel'
GROUP BY receiver )i,
messages m
WHERE i.msg=m.message;
```

But there are lots of other ways to get a list of correspondents.

Comment: This is very close! Unfortunately, it is showing me the last message from Daniel -> Admin and from Admin <- Daniel. I would like the latest message between Daniel-Admin and Daniel-John. Thanks!

Comment: OK....try SELECT i.correspondent, m.subject, m.msg FROM ( SELECT correspondent, MAX(msg) as imsg FROM (SELECT sender AS correspondent, MAX(message) msg
FROM mesages
WHERE receiver='Daniel'
GROUP BY sender
UNION
SELECT receiver AS correspondent, MAX(message)
FROM mesages
WHERE sender='Daniel'
GROUP BY receiver )l GROUP BY correspondent) i,
messages m
WHERE i.imsg=m.message;

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT Receiver, Subject, Message ,'Sender' as 'type' FROM m WHERE Sender='Danial'
UNION ALL
SELECT Sender, Subject, Message ,'Reciever' as 'type'  FROM m WHERE Receiver='Danial'
```

EDITS :

```
(SELECT Receiver, Subject, Message ,'Sender' as 'type' FROM m WHERE Sender='Danial' ORDER By message desc limit 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT Sender, Subject, Message ,'Reciever' as 'type'  FROM m WHERE Receiver='Danial'ORDER By message desc limit 1)
```

Comment: If I am correct this will output all of the messages, not just the latest message.

Comment: so you can order them by latest id desc

Comment: I would like only the latest message from each person with which I am communicating. Not all the messages in chronological order. Is that possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Receiver, Subject, Message 
FROM Messages 
WHERE Sender='Daniel'
UNION
SELECT Sender, Subject, Message
FROM Messages
WHERE Receiver='Daniel';
```

This will return all messages sent and received by 'Daniel'. To expand on this and specify which records are messages sent or received you could modify the code to the following, having 0 relate to a sent message and 1 to a received message:

```
SELECT Receiver, Subject, Message, 0 AS 'MessageType'
FROM Messages 
WHERE Sender='Daniel'
UNION
SELECT Sender, Subject, Message, 1 AS 'MessageType'
FROM Messages
WHERE Receiver='Daniel';
```

Then when you return your data you could separate it into two sets based on the 0/1 value.

I would also recommend creating a table to contain your users so that in your Messages table you can reference them by their ID instead of just by their name.

Comment: If I am correct this will output all of the messages, not just the latest message.

Comment: From your initial post I didn't read it as you only wanted the latest message - sorry. You could order by date (i assume you are storing the date of each message?) and then only select the first from each query.